# Moving/Reprojecting raster to a different central meridian?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcmap, data-frame

I have a raster set to 0-360E projected using WGS:1984.

When I modify the Data Frame Properties GCSWGS1984 to a custom meridian of 180, the raster does not move. The polygon of the continent moved but not the raster.

Also, I want the raster to display at 160. Because at 0-360, UK (of course) is cut lengthwise. So I want it at 160.

I am using ArcMap 10.3.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in ArcMap.

1. Use the shift tool to your chosen central meridian. Make sure that you modify your data frame coordinate system to your similar central meridian.
2. Clip. Return to original coordinate system. I used WGS 84, in this case. Clip the raster to the area uncovered by the shifting. This becomes tricky. You need to be exact in clipping extent as it will have impact on your seamlines.
3. Mosaic. Mosaicc using the shifted raster as mosaic operator.